# why the words font-size are not same size in different app

Tags: css, html, font-size

this is App1 image:
[image]

this is App2 image:
[image]

note: this webpage runs in a same device(my phone with Android 5.1)

source code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="Generator" content="EditPlus®">
    <meta name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no,minimal-ui"/>
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
 html,body{font-size:62.5%}

 .div1{
  font-size:2rem;
 }

 .div2{
  font-size:20px;
 }

  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="div1">哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈（2rem）</div>
 <div class="div2">哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈哈（20px）</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you viewing the apps on the same device?

Comment: yes.it's my phone.

Comment: instead of this `<meta name="viewport"            content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no,minimal-ui"/>` just do this: `<meta name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0"/>`

Comment: I try it just now.but its only different.